# Linear Algebra: Let $w=[1,2,3]_{L_1}$. Find the coordinates of w with respect to $L$ directly and by using $P^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If $L=\{t^2 , t , 1\}$ and $L_1=\{t^2 + 1, t-2 , t+3\}$ are basis for $\text{Poly}_2$ and $w=[1,2,3]_{L_1}$ (sub $L_1$).  Find the coordinates of $w$ with respect to L directly and by using $P^{-1}$ ($P$-inverse).  Where $P$ is the coordinate change matrix from the basis L to the basis $L_1$.

Unfortunately what you're about to read is as far as I got.  I just remember from my Linear Algebra class there was something with setting $w$ equal to $L_1$ and being able to solve.  I've been looking at my old Linear Algebra book and have ordered $3$ additional books through the school library, and I'm beyond lost.  I really appreciate your help/input/interest.  This is my first time, so I'm unsure if you even want to know what's going on on my paper when such a disaster as mine.

Do I set $w$ equal to $L_1$, since that's its base

$1=a(t^2+1)+b(t-2)+c(t+3)$

$2=a(t^2+1)+b(t-2)+c(t+3)$

$3=a(t^2+1)+b(t-2)+c(t+3)$

After finding $a,b,c$ need to set numbers equal to $L_1$ ,

$a=t^2+1$

$b=t-2$

$c=t+3$ ;

from here can solve for $t^2 , t , 1$ (yeah not sure about solving for $1$ either if that's what you're thinking)

Not sure about $P$ inverse, technique since having problems finding actual $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition:

$w = [1,2,3]_{L_1} = 1(t^2 + 1) + 2(t - 2) + 3(t + 3)$

$= t^2 + 1 + 2t - 4 + 3t + 9 = t^2 + (2 + 3)t + (1 - 4 + 9)$

$= t^2 + 5t + 6 = 1(t^2) + 5(t) + 6(1) = [1,5,6]_L$.

The matrix for $P^{-1}$ is actually easier to write down than the matrix for $P$, its columns are just the coordinates of the $L_1$-basis in $L$-coordinates, so:

$P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\1&-2&3\end{bmatrix}$

Thus $[w]_L = P^{-1}([w]_{L_1})$

$= \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\1&-2&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\5\\6\end{bmatrix}$

as we found before.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it looks like new users can't publicly vote a thumbs up.  Plugging w into $L_1$ and setting it equal to the polynomial with degree 2 makes much more sense.  I for some reason kept thinking I had to solve for a,b,c, and therefor was trying to find three equations to do so.  I will have to take a little time digesting $P^(-1)$, so I may have another question on it later.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's all good...I don't do it for the "rep" I do it to help. Feel free to ask away.

Comment: David, what confuses me is I'm not visualizing L and L1 as matrices. Is L the identity matrix and L1 like the identity but with 1 at the $a_13$ position, -2 at the $a_23$ position and 3 at the $a_33$ position?

Comment: They aren't matrices, they're bases-maximally linearly independent SETS. What this means is we can express every polynomial in $\text{Poly}_2$ as a *unique* linear combination of the basis elements. Essentially, they're "minimal" *generating* sets. The "coordinates" of a vector with respect to a basis are the *scalars* that are the *coefficients* of the basis elements in such a linear combination. For a polynomial $p(t) = at^2 + bt + c$, in the "usual" basis $L = \{t^2,t,1\}$, these coefficients are, of course, $a,b,c$, that is $[p]_L = (a,b,c)$.

Comment: Thank you , i appreciate that summary. It really helped put things together for me.